# Why is Google Analytics reporting Safari users on Linux OS

Tags: google-analytics, amazon, safari

I don't believe Safari can be installed on Linux, so why is Google Analytics reporting so many users with this Browser/OS combination?

Here's the breakdown of Browser and OS.

[image: os]

And here's the breakdown of Browser and Service Provider.

[image: service-provider]

So either this is a bug in Google Analytics, or Amazon is doing something strange with their user agent. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found my answer.

These hits are coming from [Pingdom Transaction Checks](https://help.pingdom.com/hc/en-us/articles/203910642-Transaction-Checks) that run every 5 minutes by logging into the website and making sure it works properly.

I'm assuming these bots are running in Linux but something must get lost in translation because Google Analytics thinks the user-agent is Safari, even though the [pingdom docs](https://help.pingdom.com/hc/en-us/articles/212979949-Google-Analytics-and-Pingdom) say the user agent is "pingdom" or requests from amazonaws.com.

See this question for more info and a solution: [Suspicious Web Traffic from Amazon.com ISP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/87405/83219)